# Extracting information from array in python

Tags: python

```
fields = [
                        ('Booktitle', 'name'), 
                        ('Date-Added', '2017-06-30 03:44:04 +0000'), 
                        ('Date-Modified', '2017-06-30 03:51:00 +0000'), 
                        ('Doi', '10.1007/978-3-642-21563-6_5'), 
                        ('Pages', '81--99'), 
                        ('Publisher', 'Springer'),
                        ('Series', 'anyseries'), 
                        ('Title', 'dummy title'), 
                        ('Volume', '6600'),
                        ('Year', '2011'), 
                        ('Bdsk-Url-1', 'http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-21563-6_5')
                    ],
```

This is my loop:

```
for entry in bib_data.entries:
    # checking how many entries do we have, for now we have 2 entries.
    print(entry)
    print(bib_data.entries[entry].fields)   
    for fields in bib_data.entries[entry].fields:
        print(fields)
```

The result which i am looking is

('Booktitle', 'name')

but i am getting the result just "Booktitle".

Comment: In your example here it's just `fields[0]`.  You may need to include the full structure of the data you are accessing.

Comment: You should list out the entire `bib_data` definition in your question. If I loop over your `fields` array it works the way you want so there must be something else going on.